# append row to parquet file on AWS s3 without read entire data

Tags: python, amazon-s3, bigdata, parquet

I have a parquet file stored in AWS s3 and it is such a large file that I can't read in memory. I want to append to the file a row that satisfies the corresponding schema.

Is it possible to append row (or rows) to the parquet file which is stored in AWS s3 without moving the entire data to the memory? additionally, I want to make it using python (via AWS lambda function, for example).